# Which is more suitable? Service or AsyncTask or JobScheduler or Thread or Firebase JobDispatcher or ...?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, alarmmanager, android-jobscheduler

I have a repeating task that sends http request and saves response in SQLite. I implement an alarm to repeat and AsyncTask to handle network job.

Since my minimum API level is 14, i think JobScheduler(need API level 21 or above) is off the table. According to [Android reference for AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads.html#references), "we suggest that you only use AsyncTask to handle work items shorter than 5ms in duration." so AsyncTask is not a suitable option too.

My network job takes few seconds to get finished and it is repeated periodically. What's the best solution to handle this network job(in terms of performance and reliability and so on)?

Comment: you can go with service as i think its best sol. for background task as i've tried this for showing notification on finishing a countdown in background

Comment: what about sync adapter ?

Comment: @antoniomerlin [You should avoid using started services that run perpetually or perform periodic work, since they continue to use device resources even when they are not performing useful tasks](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html#ap)

Comment: @Mithun Sarker Shuvro, did you ask me? :D

Comment: but what should be the best approach for example running a countdown in background task and show notification when countdown finishes and min sdk is 9

Comment: @MehranZamani yep, I am asking you to have a look :)

Comment: @Mithun Sarker Shuvro, i did it before. i think it has a different purpose since i don't have anything to upload. i only send my request and get some answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and best option is `Google Firebase` which is reliable and efficient in using mobile resources when you deal with sending/receiving notifications(Push notification instead of pulling it).

After that the best choice is `jobscheduler` if your minimum API level is **21**!

Next, `IntentService` is suitable for long tasks like network jobs because it has separate thread rather than **UI thread**(just `onHandleIntent` has separate thread).

Last shot is `Asynctask`.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of computational time maybe, I will recommend you to use Threads instead of AsyncTasks, one of the main reasons is because, in AsyncTasks you have limited options to control your task which are (onPreExecute(), doInBackground(Params...), onProgressUpdate(Progress...),onPostExecute(Result), etc.), otherwise with Threads you can syncronize times in your http request and responses more efficiently, for example sleeping and notifying your proccess in a particular period of time. If your network job takes few seconds to get finished, maybe you should sleep and notify it periodically.

Hope it helps!

Comment: i don't want to notify anything. based on what response gets back from server, i save some data in SQLite or not.

Comment: Probably, you should implement an Event handler which will be activated when you receive response from the server.

Comment: the question is where to put request code that get back from server as response?